# how to merge in R and automatically have 0 counts instead of NA

Tags: r, merge

I have two (really: multiple) vectors and am merging them together (really: to a very large df). When I merge, if there is one instance of a in one vector and not another, it appears as NA in the merged df:

```
> a=data.frame(table(letters[1:4]))
> b=data.frame(table(letters[4:10]))
> merge(a,b,by='Var1',all=1)
   Var1 Freq.x Freq.y
1     a      1     NA
2     b      1     NA
3     c      1     NA
4     d      1      1
5     e     NA      1
6     f     NA      1
7     g     NA      1
8     h     NA      1
9     i     NA      1
10    j     NA      1
> m=merge(a,b,by='Var1',all=1)
```

Is it possible to convert the NA's straight to 0, without adding an extra line of code

```
> m[is.na(m)]=0
> m
   Var1 Freq.x Freq.y
1     a      1      0
2     b      1      0
3     c      1      0
4     d      1      1
5     e      0      1
6     f      0      1
7     g      0      1
8     h      0      1
9     i      0      1
10    j      0      1
```

Reason: my df is quite large, and I do not want to use lots of processing power

Answer (score 0):

What you suggested should work directly, or at least how I understand your question:

```
> d <- data.frame(rep(NA,10),rep(1,10),rep(NA,10))
> d
rep.NA..10. rep.1..10. rep.NA..10..1
1           NA          1            NA
2           NA          1            NA
3           NA          1            NA  
4           NA          1            NA
5           NA          1            NA
6           NA          1            NA
7           NA          1            NA
8           NA          1            NA
9           NA          1            NA
10          NA          1            NA
> d[is.na(d)] <- 0
> d
rep.NA..10. rep.1..10. rep.NA..10..1
1            0          1             0
2            0          1             0
3            0          1             0
4            0          1             0
5            0          1             0
6            0          1             0
7            0          1             0
8            0          1             0
9            0          1             0
10           0          1             0
```